# php: what does . and .. mean in the output of dir->read()

Tags: php

```
<?php

$d = dir('css');
echo "Handle: " . $d->handle . "<br>";
echo "Path: " . $d->path . "<br>";

while (($file = $d->read()) !== false){
  echo "filename: " . $file . "<br>";
}
$d->close();
?>
```

Result:

```
Handle: Resource id #4
Path: css
filename: .
filename: ..
filename: css
filename: img
filename: index.html
filename: js
filename: lightbox
```

Question:

In the result, what does `.` and `..` mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: I don't think that doc has the answer to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` is the current directory and `..` is one up. Most code examples have `if-statement`s to skip over em.

Here is an example out of the `PHP` docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php#example-2318

Even on the docs, it shows the code to just ignore.

Comment: Are you assuming everyone knows and uses FileZilla?

Comment: Removed that sentence

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a reference to the current directory and `..` is the directory one level up.

For example, when changing up directories in linux, you would use `cd ..` to go up one directory.

Answer (score 0):

. means current directory in linux system

.. means parent directory in linux system